# How can I get Html table row to default to no height when div within it has visibility:none

Tags: html

In html I'm using a  to display a numbers of rows,  then between each row is another  row containing a single , that in turn contains a  with style:none. This row contains additional information for the row above and in the ful code and can be toggled to display or not by clicking on a button on the album row.

The trouble is that even when the div is hidden the row takes up vertical height, I assume this is the height of the , but how can I fix this. Or another thought can I make the  hidden or can I only do that for divs.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="1" style="display:none">
        </div>
    </td>   
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Ive done a:

http://jsfiddle.net/ijabz/zz5zo2jh/

if you remove the hidden  rows there is less of a vertical gap between the other rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply the style to your table row, not your div:

```
    <table>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr style="display:none">
    <td colspan="2">
        <div id="1">
        </div>
    </td>   
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: okay that makes sense,Ive updated http://jsfiddle.net/ijabz/zz5zo2jh/ to do this and it looks correct when hidden but Ive added in my togglebutton and that isnt working  I hopeing that is just a minsunderstanding on my part about javascript in jsfiddle or is there a code problem ?

Comment: Ive added function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return true;
if(e.style.display=="none"){ to the javscript section but doesnt persist when I share link
e.style.display="block"
}
else{
e.style.display="none"
}
return true;

Comment: can you share the jsfiddle? this doesn't seem to work.. create a new jsfiddle and hit 'save'.  also please state what you are trying to do. @PaulTaylor

Comment: Okay here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ijabz/xgLz76kn/1/ - clicking on the tracks button has no effect

Comment: the other issue ive noticed if I manually just edit the jsfiddle to display:block the extra data is al displayed within column 1 of the row above it instead of traversing both columns it seems to have ignored the colspan="2" I didnt have this problem when using div

Comment: Ah using display:table-row instead of  display:block fixed it so now working okay for me in actual code (although I still cant get jsfiddle to work )

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the visibility with a button? here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xgLz76kn/31/ @PaulTaylor

Comment: yes, thanks but my question is why doesnt the javascript in my jsfiddle have no effect when it does in my code. Its a jsfiddle question now

Comment: Youve got it the wrong way round, the javscript i wrote (without using Jquery) already works on my website, but has no effect in my jsfiddle, why doesnt my solution work with jsfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73756/discussion-between-jasper-and-paul-taylor).

Comment: got jsfiddle working in the end by changing Framework Options from 'onLoad' to 'No wrap in Head' - whatever that means

Answer (score 0):

You had to apply style to the tr. Modified your code as follows, now if display is block there is gap and when it is none, no gap:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr  style="display:block;">
    <td>

    </td>   
    <td></td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zz5zo2jh/10/).

Use `border-collapse: collapse;` on the `<table>` and `padding: 0;` on the `<tr>`.

`<tr>` elements normally have `display: table-row;` as default so I wouldn’t change that, because it might lead to some other rendering issues.

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;">
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="padding:0;" colspan="2">
        <div id="d1" style="display:none;margin:1px;"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the `margin` on the `<div>` is optional and is only there because the `padding` has been removed. This way it will look the same if the `div` is set to `display: block;`.

Comment: Ive gone with the make tr display:none as that is working for me and seems simpler, but thanks for the point about display:table-row that helped me with my javascript because I was using display:block

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you question correctly, so please let me know if not.

If you use Jquery then this would add the display=none to the row with an

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table tr').each(function (i, row) {
            console.log(i)//$(row).append("test");
            Row = $(row);
            if (Row.find("div:hidden").length == 1) {
                $(Row).attr("display","none");
            }
        });
    });
```

Updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zz5zo2jh/25/

I hope it helps